# Can I hide the Test Flight Button

Tags: ios, testflight

When an app is installed through test flight, I have this test flight link in the top left corner. This is an app that is installed on an iPad and used by employees. An employee will test it this week without being able to access any other apps on the device. Is there a way to hide the test flight button so the user can't get out and into test flight?
With swift4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an iOS feature, not something in your app. When one application opens another, iOS adds a link back to the pervious app there. If you close your app, and launch it from the home screen that link won't be there.